# Inserting Array values into database

Tags: php, mysql

i have this multi checkbox select and the code working fine my problem is send just one value in database for example i select PHP and java he insert just PHP or JAVA but i want to insert all select in phrase in database

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

 for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['name']); $i++){   
 $filename = $_POST['name'][$i];
 $selectName['name'] = "<div class='rgt' style='padding:10px;'>".$filename."</div>";    
 }               

 $getse = $DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO `testt` (name) VALUES (:name)");
 $getse->execute(array(":name"=>$selectName['name'])); 

 }
```

and this html code

```
    <form action="" method="post" id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100">
    <span class="anchor">Select Fruits</span>
    <ul id="items" class="items">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="C/C++"><label>C/C++</label><br/></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="Java"><label>Java</label><br/></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="PHP"><label>PHP</label><br/></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="HTML"><label>HTML</label><br/></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" Value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

Note : after write this code without insert in database

```
echo "<div class='rgt' style='padding:10px;'>".$filename."</div>";
```

he write all values selected but after insert in database he send just one value

sorry for bad english.

Comment: You can insert an array using `serialize()`. It will take an array and turning it to a string. http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: Or you can use `json_encode`

Comment: how can do this ??

Comment: If you assign a variable like `$str = json_encode($_POST['name']);` you save `$str` into your database. When you call it from your database, use `json_decode($row['column'],true);` instead. That will convert it back to array

Comment: Or you can also use `implode` function, for convert array to string, and store it in your DB

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

 for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['name']); $i++){   
 $filename = $_POST['name'][$i];
 $selectName['name'] = "<div class='rgt' style='padding:10px;'>".$filename."</div>";    
 }               

 $getse = $DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO `testt` (name) VALUES (:name)");
 $getse->execute(array(":name"=>serialize($selectName['name']))); 

 }
```

while retrieving use unserialize() to get as array.

sample code

```
$names=unserialize($row['name']);
```